# Google Cloud Platform - Iot Core - The connection is closed because the server is shutting down, what is causing this and is their any documentation?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, server, mqtt, disconnect, google-cloud-iot

I'm trying to diagnose why my MQTT client is disconnecting from the Google Cloud Platform IoT Core. The device happily PINGREQing every 15 minutes as expected but occasionally the following error is thrown and the device disconnects for an amount of time. The time it's offline isn't always the same and neither is the duration.

```
{
  "insertId": "r79rpxfdzvpw2",
  "jsonPayload": {
    "resourceName": "projects/<PROJECT-ID>/locations/asia-east1/registries/<REGISTRY>/devices/3172119418069326",
    "eventType": "DISCONNECT",
    "status": {
      "code": 14,
      "description": "UNAVAILABLE",
      "message": "SERVER: The connection is closed because the server is shutting down."
    },
    "disconnectType": "SERVER",
    "protocol": "MQTT",
    "serviceName": "cloudiot.googleapis.com"
  },
  "resource": {
    "type": "cloudiot_device",
    "labels": {
      "project_id": "<PROJECT-ID>",
      "device_num_id": "3172119418069326",
      "device_registry_id": "w<REGISTRY>",
      "location": "asia-east1"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2021-04-19T00:31:59.101631259Z",
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "labels": {
    "device_id": "<DEVICE-ID>"
  },
  "logName": "projects/<PROJECT-ID>/logs/cloudiot.googleapis.com%2Fdevice_activity",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2021-04-19T00:32:00.113014773Z"
}
```

Is there any documentation about this error and why it occurs? Is the device able to be notified of this event and reconnect immediately?

I haven't been able to find any information regarding this error.

Additional Info:
The MQTT client is a ESP32, connecting to IoT Core with the Google Arduino JWT library (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-iot-arduino)

Comment: Have you tried to follow the recommendations from the IoT [troubleshooting](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/support/troubleshooting#my_device_is_disconnected_from_the_mqtt_bridge) guide?

Comment: The library already has exponential back-off retry logic built in which should get it to reconnect fairly quickly. But in practice I'm seeing it take at least 17 minutes to reconnect back to IoT Core. This seams rather long for it to take to get reconnected if it is just a simple transient problem. But yes, I have tried the recommendations in the guide.

Comment: For proper diagnosis I would suggest to file a support case via Google [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) making more visibility on the issue evidence.

Comment: Does it sound reasonable for you?

Comment: Google recommends posting on here as per: https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/support/getting-support
Their issue tracker does not contain a listing for Cloud IoT so I can't raise a support case with them for it.

Comment: How about this issue tracker [template](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=310170&template=1162616)?